# mysql, use a result of if condition in a following if condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to use a resulting "column" from an if-condition in another if-condition inside the same query? I'd like to get all my documents related data once.

```
SELECT d.id, d.filename, 

IF(d.document_valid_until_further_notice = 0,
    IF(d.document_valid_until = "0000-00-00", 
        DATE_ADD(d.document_date, INTERVAL 12 MONTH),
        d.document_valid_until
    ), "0000-00-00"
) AS calculated_valid_until_date,

IF(calculated_valid_until_date != "0000-00-00", 
    DATE_SUB(calculated_valid_until_date, INTERVAL 8 WEEK, 
    "0000-00-00"
) AS calculated_alert_expiring_date, 
IF(calculated_valid_until_date > CURDATE() AND calculated_valid_until_date != "0000-00-00", 1, 0) AS expired FROM documents AS d WHERE 1 ORDER BY d.document_date DESC';
```

Now, "calculated_valid_until_date" comes out correctly, e.g. 2015-10-20, but I can't use that value in the following if-statements. with or without @ -sign. (@calculated_valid_until_date). Is there even a way or do I have to do this all with separated queries or in client side?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: On same level of query you can't use calculated aliases either you need to use whole expression again or use a sub-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.id, x.filename, 
  x.calculated_valid_until_date,
  IF(x.calculated_valid_until_date < CURDATE() AND x.calculated_valid_until_date != "0000-00-00", 1, 0) AS expired, IF(x.calculated_valid_until_date != '0000-00-00', 
    DATE_SUB(x.calculated_valid_until_date, INTERVAL 8 WEEK), '0000-00-00') AS calculated_alert_expiring_date 
FROM
(SELECT
  d.id, d.filename, d.document_date, d.calculated_alert_expiring_date, 

 IF(d.document_valid_until = '0000-00-00', DATE_ADD(d.document_date, INTERVAL 12 MONTH),
 d.document_valid_until) AS calculated_valid_until_date

  FROM documents AS d     
) x
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY x.document_date DESC
```

CREATE TABLE documents
(
  id INT,
  filename VARCHAR(50),
  document_valid_until_further_notice TINYINT(1),
  document_valid_until_date DATE,
  document_date DATE,
  document_valid_until DATE,
  calculated_valid_until_date DATE,
  calculated_alert_expiring_date DATE
);

This is how I got it working. I didn't look at the fiddle the first time so I didn't quite realize I'd have to create the table columns for "calculated_valid_until_date" and "calculated_alert_expiring_date".

But anyhow, it is working just perfect now. THANK YOU!

Comment: Noticed that this query was running extremely low so if using remember to add some where -conditions to the derived table (d.*) query as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the calculated fields of the into a derived table, then reference these calculations in an outer select from this derived table to continue your calculations:

```sql
SELECT x.id, x.filename, 
  x.calculated_valid_until_date, 
  x.calculated_alert_expiring_date,
  -- Use the derived table to do the second round of calculations 
  IF(x.calculated_valid_until_date > CURDATE() 
    AND x.calculated_valid_until_date != "0000-00-00", 1, 0) AS expired
FROM
-- Project the first round of calculations into a derived table
(SELECT
  d.id, d.filename, d.document_date,

 IF(d.document_valid_until = '0000-00-00', DATE_ADD(d.document_date, INTERVAL 12 MONTH),
 d.document_valid_until) AS calculated_valid_until_date,

IF(d.calculated_valid_until_date != '0000-00-00', 
    DATE_SUB(d.calculated_valid_until_date, INTERVAL 8 WEEK), 
    '0000-00-00') AS calculated_alert_expiring_date

  FROM documents AS d     
) x
WHERE 1 = 1
ORDER BY x.document_date DESC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62a86/2)

Comment: Thank you, almost working but now I get an error message saying "Unknown column 'd.calculated_valid_until_date' in 'field list'".
I was thinking of adding it as another (select..) but not sure how to place that in this query.. Or is it something else?

Comment: Any fields you need to use in your final / outermost select need to be returned from the inner select as well. Edit my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62a86/2) with your latest code and I'll check it.